After 24.04 install, groff bold font missing
I have a document generator that uses groff; it outputs fairly large uppercase letters in Times Roman, some of them bold. After upgrading 22.04 to 24.04, groff now shows the bold characters wrongly. They show as a very small version of the letter, with a preceding superscript 2. No idea where to look, grateful for your help.

does this itsLinuxFOSS article help?

Thanks for that. I ran font-manager, located Times New Roman, and it displays as Arabic characters (?!). In LibreOffice Writer, Times New Roman displays correctly, both as regular or bold. It's only groff that gets it wrong. I have re-installed groff, to no effect.

ahh LO see this AskUbuntu answer

OK, after lots of font hackery, I tracked it down: nothing to do with fonts, but the actual generated groff text. Specifically, it was trying to set the type size to 32 point, using the command \s32, but the manual (see The GNU Troff Manual) requires it to be \s(32. Somehow it was working before 24.04, so I guess it must have been a bug in groff that is now fixed.
